# How do I read this notation and what does it mean?

Tags: notation

The notation is `⊢P{Q}R`. To give context, the notation is from a paper called "An Axiomatic Basis for Computer Programming". From what I know, the symbol `⊢` is used to show that something(`B`) is derivable from another(`A`); i.e `A⊢B`, or `B` is a partition of `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) :

> A *Hoare triple* describes how the execution of a piece of code changes the state of the computation. A Hoare triple is of the form
>
> > $$\{ P \} C \{ Q \}$$
>
> where $P$ and $Q$ are assertions and $C$ is a command. $P$ is named the *precondition* and $Q$ the *postcondition*: when the precondition is met, executing the command establishes the postcondition.

Ref to [C.A.R. Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare)'s [An Axiomatic Basis for Computer Programming (1969)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecrary/819-f09/Hoare69.pdf) page 577 for the original notation: $P \{ Q \} R$.

And see footnote 1:

> If $P \{ Q \} R$ can be proved in our formal system, we use the familiar logical symbol for theoremhood : $\vdash P \{ Q \} R$.

See [Turnstile symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)) for $\vdash$.